# gCloud: File index.js does not exist in root directory

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am a first time user of Gcloud. When I run the following command:

```
gcloud beta functions deploy FirstBot --stage-bucket [BUCKET_NAME] --trigger-http
```

I'm getting this error in my cmd:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function l
oad error: File index.js or function.js that is expected to define function does
n't exist in the root directory.
```

I have tried 2 index.js files:
Here's no.1:

```
   /*
 HTTP Cloud Function.

 @param {Object} req Cloud Function request context.
 @param {Object} res Cloud Function response context.
*/
exports.FirstBot = function FirstBot (req, res) {
  response = "This is a sample response from your webhook!" //Default response from the webhook to show it's working

res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); //Requires application/json MIME type
  res.send(JSON.stringify({ "speech": response, "displayText": response 
  //"speech" is the spoken version of the response, "displayText" is the visual version
  }));
};
```

Here's the second one:

```
/
 HTTP Cloud Function.

 @param {Object} req Cloud Function request context.
 @param {Object} res Cloud Function response context.
*/
exports.helloHttp = function helloHttp (req, res) {
  response = "This is a sample response from your webhook!" //Default response from the webhook to show it's working

res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); //Requires application/json MIME type
  res.send(JSON.stringify({ "speech": response, "displayText": response 
  //"speech" is the spoken version of the response, "displayText" is the visual version
  }));
};
```

The name of my project is FirstBot.
I have created a bucket also.

The path of my FirstBot folder is C:\FirstBot. The index.js file is inside it.
I am following the tutorial at: https://api.ai/docs/getting-started/basic-fulfillment-conversation

Kindly help..Would be grateful!

Comment: You shouldn't be entirely changing the context of the question as your investigation continues - invalidates everything... Instead ask a new question, eventually referencing the original question as context.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? If so it is recommended to post your answer as the solution to better help the community. If you are still having issues it is recommended to run 'gcloud components update' to install the latest GCloud and follow the [deployment guide](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/filesystem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by installing npm for JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

Is the file in your `.gitignore`? [If a `.gcloudignore` isn't specified, the `.gitignore` is used to ignore files.](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore)

Adding an empty `.gcloudignore` should fix this.

Answer (score 4):

The error can also occur if you're not running the deploy command from the same folder where the index.js is located.  I.e. it's just "file not found".

Answer (score 0):

You're exceeding the `Max deployment size` limit. From [Resource Limits](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas):

[image]

Check the content of your project dir, you may have undesired stuff in there.

Comment: Hey Dan! My project dir path is C:\FirstBot and it has only 1 index.js file

Comment: Try to bump the cmd's verbosity with `--verbosity=debug` (or `info`?), maybe logs will show where's that size coming from.

Comment: Hey, so I went into my FirstBot directory and ran the command :
    C:\FirstBot>gcloud beta functions deploy FirstBot --stage-bucket supple-cheme-648 --trigger-http AND IT IS GIVING ME THIS ERROR:
    Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function l
oad error: File index.js or function.js that is expected to define function does
n't exist in the root directory.

Comment: Can you post the content of the `index.js` file (or at least the `FirstBot` and the `helloHttp` functions)?

Answer (score 0):

The command `gcloud beta functions deploy FirstBot --stage-bucket [BUCKET_NAME] --trigger-http` will deploy a function with name `FirstBot` by creating zip file with content of the directory from which your ran the command.

For the deployment to work you should:

- Run the command when you're in `C:\FirstBot`, or
- Add `--source C:\FirstBot` to your gcloud invocation to let `gcloud` know that your source code is in a different directory.

Comment: Hey! I ran the command from C:\FirstBot from the start , but I'm getting the error as described in the question!

Comment: Can you try running it with `--local-path` flag? If it doesn't help can you download the zip file gcloud uploads and see if it has content of `C:\FirstBot`?

Comment: `--local-path` does not seem to be available in `gcloud functions deploy` or `gcloud beta functions deploy`

Comment: `--local-path` flag was replaced with `--source` since I wrote that answer. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a bucket to the project via the console solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

II was having a similar issue and solution for me was pretty easy to apply but hard to find.
In case someone can help. I noticed that my .gcloudignore had this line

`#!include:.gitignore`

and my .gitignore these two

```
# Compiled JavaScript files    
**/*.js
**/*.js.map
```

Therefore .js files where being ignored and gcloud could not find index.js.

As i don't want compiled files to be in repository, i ended by removing the include at .gcloudignore and add the specific ignores directly, such as node_modules and sensitive data